# The difference between coniunctivus and imperativus when expressing commands

Tags: grammar-choice, conjunctive, imperative

What is the rule for choosing coniunctivus or imperativus when expressing commands? I know, that imperativus has only second person forms, so one is forced to use coniunctivus for other persons. Are there other rules however that make sentences with these modes different?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Latin/Lesson_2-Subjunctive_Use#Indirect_Commands) seems helpful - about use of subjunctive for indirect commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm. My understanding is that the bare subjunctive as a positive request/command is actually rather rare in classical Latin. Woodcock's *New Latin Syntax*, p. 97, after a discussion of *noli, nolite* + infinitive as *more* polite than *ne* + perfect subjunctive, tells us:

> Besides *noli, nolite* with the infinitive, the following periphrases also are frequently employed for the sake of politeness: (i) For positive commands, *fac, facite*, with a quasi-subordinate subjunctive: *Fac mihi scribas; facite mihi scribatis,* "See that you write to me." The subordinating conjunction *ut* is usually omitted. Similarly *vide*, "see that . . .", and *velim*, "I should like . . ." are used with the subjunctive: Plaut *Asin* 755 *scribas vide plane et probe*, "see that you write clearly and properly"; Cic. *Fam*. 9, 12, 2 *tu velim animo forti sis*, "I should like you to be of brave heart." (ii) For negative commands *fac ne . . ., facite ne . . .*, and *vide ne . . .* are used. Rather more frequent are *cave* (sometimes *caveto*) and *cavete* with, or more often without, *ne*: Plaut. *Most.* 324 *cave ne cadas*, "mind you don't fall"; Cic. *Att.* 3, 17, 3 *cave vereare*, "mind you don't fear."

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to give a command, use imperative.
If you want to request someone to do something, use conjunctive.
The difference between *curre* and *curras* is similar to the difference between "run" and "please run".