# Imperative vs Hortatory Subjunctive

Tags: grammar-choice, conjunctive, imperative

According to [this](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/hortatory-subjunctive), Subjunctive can be used to express "an exhortation or a command".

When should Hortatory Subjunctive be used and when Imperative is favoured? What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: I tend to think of subjunctive as more polite or gentle, while imperative is direct and a bit rude—but on the other hand, *Domine, dona eis requiem*. Good question.

Comment: Take a look at this older question: [The difference between coninuctivus and imperativus when expressing commands](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/349/79). If you think it answers your question, we can turn this into a duplicate (permanent link) to make the other question easier to find. If it doesn't, can you explain what's missing? It's your call.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta My question should be turned into a duplicate. Joel's answer on the other question helps a bit but the difference seems not so easy to undestand especially considering Draconis's comment.

Comment: I turned it into a duplicate. If a specific question about the difference in tone (or something else) arises, you can always ask a new, more specific question. It may also depend on era and other factors, but I don't know how.